# jaxws jakarta generate soap client

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, soap, jax-ws

I am writing a SOAP client using Jakarta EE with Java 17. I would like to have the generated class using wrapper style. I believe I need to do it via the binding file. But after I have configured it using `enableWrapperStyle`, it is still generating the parameters as `Holder`

Maven configuration

```
....
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.xml.ws</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.xml.ws-api</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
      <version>4.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxws-ri</artifactId>
      <type>pom</type>
      <version>4.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
....

       <plugin>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <wsdlDirectory>src/main/resources/wsdl</wsdlDirectory>
          <bindingDirectory>src/main/resources/wsdl</bindingDirectory>
          <wsdlFiles>
            <wsdlFile>myService.wsdl</wsdlFile>
          </wsdlFiles>
          <args>
            <arg>-B-XautoNameResolution</arg>
          </args>
          <bindingFiles>
            <bindingFile>bindings.xml</bindingFile>
          </bindingFiles>
          <packageName>com.company.myService</packageName>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>wsimport</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
```

binding file

```
<bindings xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jaxws"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jaxws
                      https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jaxws/wsdl_customizationschema_3_0.xsd"
          version="3.0">
    <enableWrapperStyle>true</enableWrapperStyle>
</bindings>
```

But generated the client still uses `Holder`.